# Cleaning of chlorbutyl plungers

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs, cleaning, rubber

This is my first post, so please bear with me.

At work I have some chlorobutyl plungers that I need to clean from any residual material that might be left after production.

A colleague of mine told me that he has seen a GMP (Good Manufacturing Practice) description of how to clean chlorobutyl plungers, but was unable to find it. It relates to pharmaceutical industry and the standard approved ways of working. The plungers I am referring to are commonly used in penfill cartridges for subcutaneous injections.

Any advice on how to clean the chlorobutyl plungers (e.g. with what chemicals, under what conditions) to ensure that there are no residual solutions/oils/materials on the plungers?